# What combination of NAND and NOR is equivalent to $a \lor b$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am stuck on this problem and needed some help.

Write $(a \lor b)$ using just $\uparrow$ (nand), then using just $\downarrow$ (nor)

[image: truth table for or, nor, and nand]

I have tried many different combinations of nand and nor but have gotten nowhere. Any help getting off the ground would be much appreciated!

Comment: why not just ~NOR

Comment: for this problem you are not allowed to use not ONLY nor and nand

Comment: Isn't $\mathrm{Not}(x) = \mathrm{Nand}(x, x)$?

Comment: Probably because these are the gates used in hardware.

Comment: Hint: first, figure out how to take an expression $A$ and, using the NOR (or NAND) gate, turn it into the expression $\neg A$. If you're starting with the NOR gate, use the fact that $\neg NOR(a, b)$ is equivalent to $a \lor b$. If you're starting with the NAND gate, use a similar tactic to get an expression equivalent to $a \land b$. Then, use De Morgan's laws to express $\lor$ in terms of $\land$ and $\neg$.

Answer (score 2):

Denote NAND by $|$, then
$$A\lor B=\neg\neg(A\lor B)=\neg A|\neg B=(A|A)|(B|B)$$

Comment: You solved it for AND I need to solve it for OR

Comment: Look at how healynr did this.  See if that suggest what to do in other cases.

Comment: @CoderMan1223 Fixed